# Filter for specific tags on Zendesk API using Zenpy on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, zendesk, zendesk-api

Need some help, while trying to retrieve some tickets with Zenpy, I encounter that when I search for more than one tag, they fetch all the data related to both tags, is there a way to filter only for the tickets who have both tags?

An example of my script is:

`zenpy_client.search(tags = ["tag1","tag2"], created_between=[to_date, from_date], type='ticket', minus='negated')`

Could you help on that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should combine the tags in a string as follows:

```
zenpy_client.search(tags = "tag1 tag2", created_between=[to_date, from_date], type='ticket', minus='negated')
```

Same way you would search in the UI. See [this article](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408882086298-Searching-tickets).